# Windows 10 home updates fail with error 0x80070057

Tags: windows-10, updates

I am a regular computer user and i am using lenovo Z51-70 laptop which runs on windows 10 home. Recently i saw i stopped getting new updates for my OS and i am getting an error message like the one shown below

```
Update error - There are some problem installing updates, But we will try again later..........
This may help(0x80070057)
```

I am totally fed up seeing this for a long time. May I know what problem it is? Also how to get rid of it?

Comment: Try running a sfc /scannow or the Windows Update troubleshooter. This error could happen for many reasons. Start by following this link and go through the troubleshooting steps: https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/fix-windows-update-error-0x80070057/#:~:text=Error%200x80070057%20usually%20occurs%20when,with%20the%20Windows%20Update%20process.

Comment: [edit] your question to indicate what the last update that was installed was.  You should also indicate what version of Windows 10 you are using.

Comment: I am using windows 10 home version 21H2 and OS Build 19044.1200 and it is a 64 Bit operating system